# Spring create a method controller that executes in every page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Currently , I am implementing the hreflang meta tag in my site and I am facing a problem , I need to create a method that must be executed in every page (in order to load the hreflangs into the model and pass them to the JSP) of my site and this method must have this parameters `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response`.

I tried with this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/*"})
public class GLobalPageController  {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void setupHreflangs(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        //code
    }

}
```

But its not working , any idea about how can I achieve this ?

Comment: maybe with an aspect you weave into the controllers? see AOP: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: That is something you can do with either a `HandlerInterceptor` or a `@ControllerAdvice` containing an `@ModelAttribute` annotated method.